# Manipulating root files in images without being root?

Tags: linux, file-permissions, embedded, disk-image

In our environment we have linux developer PCs and several embedded boards. The embedded boards are booted from an image. Those image files should be created/modified on the developer PCs. Mounting is no problem:

```
mount /scratch/image.img /scratch/mounted-image -o loop,user
```

would be enough.

The problem is users can mount it, but not access files that are belonging to root in the image (the image is usually ext2). What I need is a way that everything in that mounted dir, that belongs to uid 0, is mapped to a different uid and vice-versa.

I googled already for something, but the results where disappointing (e.g. only something like fakeroot, which is not suitable in such a situation; of course sudo is also not possible in this situation).

Comment: This could be solved with a fuse-based "translator". I actually created something somewhat similar a while ago. It would need some work to do what you want. I think I know you. If so, you shall be able to find me in IRC.

Answer (score -1):

Why are these images owned by root? All of your problems are caused by this issue. Simply chown the files to a proper owner and grant permissions in the traditional unix style.

Comment: No, not the images are owned by root - but the files within the images (at least some). And as they are usually boot images, they have the usual owner - e.g. /etc/passwd (in the image) is owned by root.